# Overflooding because the tons of rain? or is the WELL- PUMP broken?

Tags: well, well-pump

About two weeks ago, I noticed there is water slowly coming up from around the well-pump pit and puddling around the well-pump.

Here are some facts:

1. We've been having a lot of rain in the past month, 6 weeks.
2. The water table is kind of low in our area.
3. Our sump pump runs every 5 minutes - I timed it.
4. The well-pump is on the lower middle of a sloped backyard and when I step anywhere within 5 feet, even uphill from the well pump, the yard is wet.
5. The water pressure was fine until a couple days ago. Before; the shower can be running while using the any sink and there will be no difference in the water pressure. Now If any two faucets are in use, the pressure drops by half.

My thought is that with all this rain, the water table is so high that the water is flooding up around the lower end of the yard where the WELL is located. That will also explain why the sump pump is going off every 5 minutes.

My question is: Am I right in thinking the rain is causing the water table to overflow? or is there a problem with the well-pump?

I just don't want to call the well-pump company to charge me $100 just to tell everything is alright and just wait until the water table goes down.

Comment: Sounds right to me. Water tables do rise and fall with rain seasons. The operation of the sump is definitely indicating that. One could put in a drainage pipe in to give the water some place to go. We had a spring fed well and this is what we did so the ground around the well wasn't muddy.

Comment: Are you asking about your well pump?  Sump   or Flooding or all three?

Comment: You just noticed that when you turn on 2 faucets the pressure is halved, this is quite normal for most homes, if your well has high water it can only make the well pumps job easier and that would also be why the sump is cycling every 5 minutes there is nothing wrong with your system.

Comment: @RobertMoody  I am not referring to the sump pump. I am referring to the water well pump and the water flooding up  the yard,

Comment: May be edit part about water pump running.

Comment: If there's water atop the cistern and the pump shuts off (ever...) every 5min, then **the motor is tripping out on over heat, or the float's messed up**. Given that there's two problems here (possibly unrelated, but if they are related and you're not on city water) I'd be checking the power situation. I.e., you lost, or are intermittently losing, a leg.

Comment: broken pipe?  If you shut the well pump breaker off for a few hours do the problems abate?

Answer (score 0):

Your well is likely fine just rising with the water table but you might want to check your pressure tank as suggested above. A change in water pressure suggests something is not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of water line is in the ground surrounding the pump at the bottom?  With that much water from the rain and the ground being saturated, there is a possibility that the ground around that pipe has 'caved in'.  Can you remove the well cover and using a strong flashlight see around the pipe any distance from the surface?  My well originally from about 40 years ago only had black tubing around my pump line...the well caved in and when the well diggers came back out to punch it back out for me, they used PVC pipe drilled with holes (my well is 180' deep)so the natural spring could seep into it as a replacement and protection.

Comment: You state well pump pit. Is the pump a submersible pump? Is it a jet pump? Is the well pump flooded? Is there electrical in the pit? Where is the pressure switch? Where is the water tank? Can you post a picture of the inside of the pit, if it is wet do not go in it.

Answer (score 0):

> The water pressure was fine until a couple days ago. Before; the shower can be running while using the any sink and there will be no difference in the water pressure. Now If any two faucets are in use, the pressure drops by half.

and

> The well-pump is on the lower middle of a sloped backyard and when I step anywhere within 5 feet, even uphill from the well pump, the yard is wet.

**Strongly suggest** that you might have a leak in the pipe (which I assume is underground, but you have not stated) from the well pump to the house.